# No named parameter with the name 'nullOk' error in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

After having horrible problems I finished by passing my project into another one. But now It gives me this error after trying to run my program. Which I never see before. And also, I didn't edit these codes because they are libraries.

```
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.0.3/lib/src/widget/app_bar.dart:147:57: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);
                                                        ^^^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1918:24: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ScaffoldState of(BuildContext context) {
                       ^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/neumorphic-0.4.0/lib/src/components/app_bar.dart:32:57: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);
                                                        ^^^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1918:24: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ScaffoldState of(BuildContext context) {
                       ^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/neumorphic-0.4.0/lib/src/components/text_field.dart:953:32: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
        MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true)?.navigationMode ??
                               ^^^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:818:25: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context) {
                        ^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/neumorphic-0.4.0/lib/src/neumorphic/theme.dart:390:52: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
      _cupertinoOverrideTheme.resolveFrom(context, nullOk: nullOk),
                                                   ^^^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.0.3/lib/src/widget/app_bar.dart:147:57: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);
                                                        ^^^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1918:24: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ScaffoldState of(BuildContext context) {
                       ^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/neumorphic-0.4.0/lib/src/components/app_bar.dart:32:57: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
    final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true);
                                                        ^^^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1918:24: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ScaffoldState of(BuildContext context) {
                       ^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/neumorphic-0.4.0/lib/src/components/text_field.dart:953:32: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
        MediaQuery.of(context, nullOk: true)?.navigationMode ??
                               ^^^^^^
../../Developer/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/media_query.dart:818:25: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context) {
                        ^^
../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/neumorphic-0.4.0/lib/src/neumorphic/theme.dart:390:52: Error: No named parameter with the name 'nullOk'.
      _cupertinoOverrideTheme.resolveFrom(context, nullOk: nullOk),


    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
                                                   ^^^^^^
```

Here's my pubspec.yaml

```yaml
name: Test


environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  mqtt_client: ^8.0.0
  provider: ^4.3.2+2
  get_it: ^5.0.1
  vibration: ^1.7.2
  clay_containers: ^0.2.2
  local_auth: ^0.6.2+1
  flutter_secure_storage: ^3.3.3
  neumorphic: ^0.4.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.8
  flutter_neumorphic: ^3.0.3
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/homestadelogo.png
    - images/morning.png
  fonts:
    - family: OpenSans
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/assets/fonts/OpenSans.ttf
    - family: myLamp
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/assets/fonts/mylamp.ttf
```

What should I do?
If you need more details, just ask me.

Comment: Do you have a scaffold in your app?

Comment: Yes. Why? Basically everywhere in my .dart files

Comment: I just posted my pubspec.yaml file if needed

Comment: I am getting this error also and have no idea why or how to fix it

Comment: This seems to be an error in flutter_neumorphic. They will need to patch this to be up to the current Flutter standards.

Comment: To update a little bit, this error is created from many things, I think that every answer in this post can solve the problem that you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve my problem. For my case, which could not be yours, I deleted the "build" folder, then run it without doing something. Then flutter created the file again automatically. I personally couldn't find "build" on Android Studio. So I run it on VSCode which showed the folder. So try it.

Answer (score 12):

Several `nullOk` parameters have been removed as part of null safety post-migration. You can read more on the [corresponding design doc](https://flutter.dev/go/eliminating-nullok-parameters) and its upcoming [migration guide](https://github.com/flutter/website/pull/4921/files?short_path=3199315#diff-3199315d2df2c0bacf40f271defb30d51d53f1f9cc3bbaeb0773e1f061bbb48e).

TL;DR you can try to use `.maybeOf(context)` instead of `.of(context, nullOk: true);`

You may have to update your dependencies to make it work.

Comment: I updated them all but it now gives the error " Error: Method not found: 'Scaffold.maybeOk'.
    final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.maybeOk(context);"

Comment: @Miles Answerer likely meant `maybeOf` instead of `maybeOk`. Take a look at their links.

Answer (score 12):

After lots of effort, I found a successful answer to remove this error.

If you have added SVG dependency in **pubspec.yaml** so you have replaced this to

**flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3**

Answer (score 6):

If you are using **neumorphic** ,

Locate,

> home/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_neumorphic-3.0.3/lib/src/widget/app_bar.dart

Search For,

> final ScaffoldState scaffold = Scaffold.maybeOf(context);

try to use,
`.maybeOf(context);` instead of `.of(context, nullOk: true);`

Answer (score 4):

For anyone here, what worked for me was just to update my dependencies and then run `flutter clean`

Answer (score 3):

Finally, Solved.

Alter the `media_query.dart` file, search for : `static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context)` function, then modify it to  :

```
static MediaQueryData of(BuildContext context, { bool nullOk = false })
```

Answer (score 1):

- First, open your **pubspec.yaml** file.
- Click ***Pub outdated*** menu at the top right corner. If are using **android studio** IDE.

After a couple of seconds later you will see a list of the **package names** with **version numbers**.

- Update all dependencies with the latest version number. Also, you have to update **flutter_launcher_icons** version under **dev_dependencies** as well.
- Click, ***Pub get*** the menu for update.

After successful getting all packages. **Run** your App.

Still, you may have some errors in older uses codes.
For example, use:

```
 Scaffold.of(context)
```

instead of

```
 Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true)
```

Because for null safety nullOk parameters have been removed as part of post-migration.

Note: See proper documentation of uses. https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold/of.html

Again **Run** your project and enjoy happy coding. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Moving :/Flutter/.pub-cache folder to another place worked for me. I did not delete because it affects other projects maybe. Then I will put it its place again.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem and found that it was an issue with the dependencies in this case its:
flutter_neumorphic
neumorphic

you can upgrade them to versions that are null-safety compliant or you can run: flutter clean, incase both dependencies are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

i Fixed this problem by using

```
Scaffold.of(context)
```

Instead of

```
Scaffold.of(context, nullOk: true)
```